# Dynamic refresh background-image with ngStyle In AngularJs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-style, angularjs-ng-style

When i use Angular to **dynamic change div 's backgroundImage**, i find there are two ways to set backgrond-image:

**first:**

`<div style="background:url({{example_expression}})"></div>`

**the second:**

`<div ng-style="{backgroundImage: 'url({{example_expression}})'}"></div>`

But when i change `example_expression`, only the first way can dynamically change the backgroundImage.

There is a example in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iss7x1KlNvRemdIUGzZ1?p=preview)

**What's wrong with ngStyle?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ng-style` should not contain `{{}}` interpolation directive, you could directly access scope variable there. Also `backgroundImage` should be  `'background-image'`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+ example_expression+')'}"></div>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iss7x1KlNvRemdIUGzZ1?p=preview)