# AngularJS Error: $interpolate:interr Interpolation Error with $routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, angular-routing

I am trying to load dynamic links from the json to into my iframe template. When I load the iframe page, this error pops up. I don't really know why. This is the first time I've seen this error. Here is the code below.

Controller

```
app.controller('apps', [
'$scope', 
'$http', 
'contentService',
'gotoService',
'getIndex', 
'$routeParams', function($scope, $http, contentService, gotoService,  getIndex, $routeParams){
 contentService.then(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;   // access all data
    $scope.appsList = $scope.data.appsList;  // list of shortcuts

    // change url to links
    $scope.goTo= function(url){
        gotoService.getLink(url);
    }

    // get index
    $scope.getIndex = function(index){
        getIndex.current(index);
    }

    // embed in iframe
    $scope.link = function(){
        $scope.indexRoute = $routeParams.index;
       return $scope.appsList[$scope.indexRoute].url;
    }
});

}]);
```

iframe template

```
<iframe ng-controller="apps" ng-src="{{link()}}" width="800"   height="600">
</iframe>
```

apps icon template

```
<div class="apps-background" ng-click="goTo(a.link+'/'+$index); getIndex($index);" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{a.image}})', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-size': 'cover'}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have interpolation directive inside a ng-style directive expression, you need to correct it like below.

```
<div class="apps-background" 
  ng-click="goTo(a.link+'/'+$index); getIndex($index);" 
  ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+ a.image + ')', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-size': 'cover'}">
```

[**Similar answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31145646/2435473)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I changed the code in my controller to this and it worked perfectly.

```
app.controller('apps', [
'$scope', 
'$http', 
'contentService',
'gotoService',
'getIndex', 
'$routeParams', 
'$sce', function($scope, $http, contentService, gotoService, getIndex,  $routeParams, $sce){
   contentService.then(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;   // access all data
    $scope.data = data;   // access all data
    $scope.appsList = $scope.data.appsList;  // list of shortcuts

    // change url to links
    $scope.goTo= function(url){
        gotoService.getLink(url);
    }

    // get index
    $scope.getIndex = function(index){
        getIndex.current(index);
    }

    // embed in iframe
    $scope.link = function(){
        $scope.indexRoute = $routeParams.index;
       return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.appsList[$scope.indexRoute].url);
    }
});

}]);
```