# How to use ngStyle with interpolation inside a style rule

Tags: angular, templates

I have a ngFor loop that iterates over an object (selectedUser). I'm trying to use a value from this property inside 'background-image' style rule, but i keep getting parsing errors.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of selectedUser.user">
 <div class="user-img" ngStyle="{'background-image':'url(/assets/img/{{ user.image }})'}" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what the correct syntax for something like this would be?

Comment: you need not use `{{ }}` there,                                                                    
`ngStyle="{'background-image':'url(/assets/img/' +user.image +')'}"` should work.

Comment: also this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145558/dynamic-refresh-background-image-with-ngstyle-in-angularjs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), so please mark this duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the annotation **`{{}}`**

```
 <div class="user-img" ngStyle="{'background-image':'url(/assets/img/' +user.image +')'}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like below

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of selectedUser.user">
 <div class="user-img" ngStyle="{'background-image':'url(/assets/img/'+ {{ user.image }} + ')'}" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```